# Magento 1.9: Add property to Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-attribute

I try to implement a Honeypot on the customer/create form. Therefor I want to implement one input that is prohibited to fill out. All input fields are put into a Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute with several scope properties like scope_is_required that are used for the decision. I want to add a property like scope_is_prohibited but have no idea how.

What I don't want is to add some hardcoded $_REQUEST['myprohibitedfield'] into the validation as I want to keep the field name as flexible as possible, even might add several such fields.

What I do have is a working module with overwritten Models.

Did anyone have the same problem? Or maybe a totally different approach instead of a scope property?